Why does the DSP textbook mention that unit step function u[n] is a sum of delta functions from -inifinity to n?
The DSP textbook from Oppenheim has several equation between unit step function and delta functions.
Some forms like this:
$$u[n] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \delta[n-k] $$
and this:
$$\delta[n] = u[n]-u[n-1]$$
are very intuitive to understand and have some real use case.
However, there is another definition which I don't quite understand why we need it:

The unit step is related to the unit impulses by
$$u[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^n \delta[k]$$

Is there any specific use case for this form?

The 3rd form is just the inverse of the 2nd equation. In the continuous domain, we can say

"the Dirac delta is the derivative of the unit step hence the unit step is the integral over the Dirac delta".

In the discrete domain this becomes:

"The Kronecker Delta is the one sample difference of the unit step and hence the unit step is the cumulative sum over the Kronecker Delta."

In essence equation 2 and 3 are the same thing just expressed as inverses of each other. You use eq (2) if you want to express the Kronecker Delta as a function the unit step and you use eq (3) if you want to express the Kronecker Delta as a function of the unit step.
You can turn eq (1) into eq (3) and vice versa by a substitution of the the summation index.

In general
$$ x[n] = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} x[i] \delta[n-i]$$
This is true for any arbitrary $x[n]$.

So you can get the proof from other books or on google. But remember this simple thing-

integration of unit impulse is unit step
integration of unit step is unit ramp
Similarly
derivative of unit step is unit impulse
derivative of unit ramp is unit step

